# Creating a qml connection to a cpp class object with nested classes

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am trying to create one connection to my custom cpp class "EState".
EState contains three classes and two of those subclasses have some of their own classes.

So far I am able to access the variables the following way in QML:

```
// ...
Estate.B.bSub.targetSpeed = 0
// ...
```

The EState constructor initializes the subclasses and the subclasses initializes itsubclasses.

//main.cpp

```
QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

EState *state = new EState();


engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("EState", state);
```

//end of main

//top level class

```
class EState : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(EAState *A MEMBER mA NOTIFY aChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(EBState *B MEMBER mB NOTIFY bChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QList<ECState*> Cs MEMBER mCs NOTIFY csChanged)

public:
    EState();
    ~EState(){}

    EAState * mA;
    EBState * mB;
    QList<ECState *> mCs;
    ECState *COne;
    ECState *CTwo;

signals:
    void aChanged();
    void bChanged();
    void csChanged();
};

EState::EState()
{
    mA = new EAState();
    mB = new EBState();
    COne = new ECState();
    CTwo = new ECState();

     mCs = {COne, CTwo};
}
```

//end of top class

//middle class

```
class EBState : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT    
    Q_PROPERTY(BSub * bSub MEMBER mBSub NOTIFY bSubChanged)

public:
    EBState();
    ~EBState(){}

    BSub *  mBSub;              

signals:
    void bSubChanged();
};

EBState::EBState()
{  
    mBSub = new BSub();
}
```

//end middle class

//innermost class

```
class BSub : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(float targetSpeed MEMBER mTargetSpeed NOTIFY targetSpeedChanged)

public:
    BSub ()
    ~BSub (){}
    float mTargetSpeed = 0;

signals:
    void targetSpeedChanged(); 
};

MSub::MSub()
{
     mTargetSpeed = 0;
}
```

//end of inner most class

In QML I would like to receive the signals of the inner classes like the following way (or similar):

```
 Connections
 {
      target: EStates

      B.bSub.onTargetSpeedChanged: 
      {
           console.log(targetSpeed);          
      }     
 }
```

Current Error message is:
qrc:​/​QML/​main.​qml:​204 Non-​existent attached object

Comment: `mBSub` is just a pointer, Where have you created the object? The same for `mB`. Also change `ontargetSpeedChanged` to `onTargetSpeedChanged`

Comment: mB is initialized in EState's constructor and the same is true for mBSub in B's constructor. ontargetSpeedChanged  is a typo on end when writing this.

Comment: If there are types then correct it, if you have not provided the necessary code to avoid confusion then show it, provide a [MRE]

Comment: Ok, I updated the code. Is what I am trying to do int QML legal? Am I allowed to target the top level class and then listen for signals from the subclasses?

Comment: It is valid but you are using inappropriate terminology, they are not nested classes but nested objects. see my answer.

Comment: Property-names cannot be capitalized, then QEngine thinks it's an attached property, as the errors tells you.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 errors:

- A Typo in the name of the object EState in QML since you register it as EState: `setContextProperty("EState", state);` but you use it as `target: EStates`.
- The Connections target refers to the object that has the signal, ie `EState.B.bSub` and not `EState`.

Considering the above, the solution is:

```
Connections
{
    target: EState.B.bSub

    onTargetSpeedChanged: 
    {
        console.log(EState.B.bSub.targetSpeed);
        // or
        // console.log(target.targetSpeed);    
    }     
}
```

Comment: Thanks that is working now. So I will need to create a Connection to each object in the top level object and below? I was hoping to avoid that.

Comment: @OTR Who has the targetSpeedChanged signal? Because the bSub object of object B of the EState object, that is to say the object: "EState.B.bSub" and not "Estate", QML is not interested if object/classes are nested, only the object that has the signal. Well, if the signal belongs to another object (target) you will have to use another "Connections", those are the "Connections" rules.

Comment: @OTR On the other hand if my answer helped you then mark it as correct, if you don't know how to do it then check the [tour].